# Ошибка проверки CSRF. Запрос отклонён

Tags: django

view.py

```
def create_question (request, title, text,):
questions.title = title
questions.text = text
questions.save()
return  question_detail(request, id )
```

представление

```
 <form action="/create_question/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="textarea">
      <label for="email">Тема</label>
    <input type="title"  class="form-control" id="email">
    <label for="textarea">Текст</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="text"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="Ответить" class="btn btn-default">Создать</button>
</form>
```

csrf токен есть, в чем проблема не пойму.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но вполне возможно, что не передали CSRF в шаблон. Надо дописать:

```
context = {}
context.update(csrf(request))
```